# Unable to connect to Orion Message Broker from Wirecloud GE

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-wirecloud

I want to use the Orion related widgets available at https://store.lab.fiware.org/ to manage my local Orion instance from Wirecloud.

Problem is that while providing all parameters, I can't connect to my Orion instance (both wirecloud and orion are running locally on separated Docker containers). I have configured the Wirecloud containter to deploy the ngsi-proxy by followin the instructions in https://github.com/conwetlab/ngsi-proxy (apt-get method).

For instance, my NGSI Browser is configured with the following parameters:

[image]

And I am getting 404 with no feedback:

[image]

My Orion instance has no security configured, services or tenants, its brand new with some entities created to test.

Do you know if I am missining some configuration? Do you know of a logfile where I could find some more rich feedback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the NGSI browser must be connected to the Orion Context Broker port (1026).

Another problem was that I was attempting to connect to my dockerized orion by using the URL http://localhost:1026/ from another docker contaniner of Wirecloud. Changing the localhost URL to the actual IP of the docker 172.17.0.3 enabled connectivity between two docker instances.